# Extreme difference in navigation speed between Win7 and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10

I have dual boot 13.10 and Windows 7. After the installation of the driver `rtl8188ce` in both Ubuntu and Windows, Ubuntu holds the connection, unlike before. But there is a very big difference in navigation speed.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please tell us which network card you have. Post the output of `lspci | grep etw`.

Comment: How did you install this driver? Did you install the exact same driver for Windows as well? What steps have you taken so far? Please explain everything.

Comment: and alvar and terdon....so. because it doesn't work, as Windows after these procedures...can i buy a lan usb...there is a model d-link that in 13.04 Works well, i could buy it? In Your opinion, can i resolve the issue with this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrative priveleges over the router, I suggest you change the WPA2 encryption method to AES. It is more secure. Also, if the router uses WPA and WPA2 mixed mode, change it to WPA2 only.

Second, if the connection is made as expected, but seems to drop for no apparent reason, there are a few things we can try:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee swenc=1
```

Also, find your country code here:

```
iw reg get
```

If it shows as 00, that's a one-size-fits-all...maybe code. Let's try setting your code explicitly. Find it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Set it with:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your actual country code, if not Iceland.

Finally, tell your system you wish to always use your preferred network rather than roaming to another: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

In order to make some or all of these permanent, we'll need to amend a few files. First, tell us if the problem is resolved.

If none of these steps help, I suggest you compile a later version of the driver. Please obtain a temporary wired ethernet connection. Please download this file to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.13.2/backports-3.13.2-1.tar.gz  Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13.2-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

You will get a warning about signing that you may safely ignore. Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: Hi Chili....thank you so much for your answear...Wpa 2 AES, terminal , ecc....
But the the problem isn't resolved....
damn rtl.....
Another suggestion ?
Thank you....have a good evening

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Answering Terdon: lspci | grep etw
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Alvar: I have installed driver by https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver

Comment: Thank you so much guys.....I hope to resolve this problem

Comment: at least, if I can not resolve this issue, do you think I could buy an external card?

Comment: Did you try the later driver I suggested?

Comment: If Yes, any suggestions?....
of course if I can get this with damn realtek :-)

Comment: Not sure I understand your response. Did you download, compile and install it? Did it help?

Comment: CHILI555 STEP BY STEP ALL PROCEDURES....BUT RTL STILL NOT WORKING WELL AND , AT THE SAME TIME, W7 CONNECTIONS RUSH......should i buy an usb card lan? Have i tried all ways?

Comment: If you can't improve it with the swenc=1 parameter as above, then I am out of suggestions.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

and alvar and terdon....so. because it doesn't work, as Windows after these procedures...can i buy a lan usb...there is a model d-link that in 13.04 Works well, i could buy it? In Your opinion, can i resolve the issue with this way?

Comment: Guys....i don't know if was the procedures or the installation of driver of windows but now is woriking very well.....thank you very much