# Why does this action fix my Wi-fi?

Tags: wireless

I found the below answer to fix my intermittent Wi-fi connection:

[Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again)

Questions:

- Can someone explain in plain English why would this work, because my connection was never asking for any other router's authorization?
- Can someone also explain why the MAC device address entry is entered in the BSSID, while there is another MAC device entry in the same pop-up box? What is the conceptual difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason assigning a mac address worked is because you had several networks that your computer was picking up all at or stronger then your connection so your computer was roaming continually from the strongest signal network to the next.

BSSID is the MAC address of your router.

The other MAC address is the MAC address of your wireless device.

Comment: Regarding the first part, is this so even if the Wi-fi was already connected to the router in question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes even if wifi was already connected.

Comment: Ok, so it's like the Wi-fi was getting distracted by many lights, even though I told it to focus on a specific one. So whenever a little drop in signal happen, it would start looking at all the surrounding lights.

Comment: Yes that is what it was doing, the only thing with the Mac Address set like it is if you take the computer some where else that you want to connect too you will have to remove the MAC Address so it can connect to your new network.

Comment: Sounds good. Also, by the third part, "wireless device" you mean my computer's own, I take it.

Comment: Yes your computers own wireless device.

Comment: Good deal, man. This hopefully can also inform people with a similar issue.