# weak wifi signal acer E1-570G

Tags: wireless

i have recently installed the new version of ubuntu and i'm receiving a weak wifi signal.

You can find al information (wireless script)  in this link. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9612203/

can somebody help me?

Comment: You posted the script itself; we need the file it produces after you run it on your system.

Comment: Hi, first of al thanks for helping me out, and you are right, my bad, ik hope this is it. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9617976/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wireless script, we see several access points named 'TELENETHOMESPOT' and your wireless device is disconnecting and reconnecting to roam from one to the other. At the time you ran the script, you were connected to one with signal strength of 46. There is another nearby with signal strength 49. I suggest you ask Network Manager to bind to it as here: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Also, I suggest that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
modprobe -r ath9k
modprobe ath9k
exit
```

Comment: thank you, This has been helpfull for restoring a stable connenction with my wifi network, but my connenction is still significantly weaker then before i installed ubuntu. Is there any sollution regarding that problem?

Comment: @jozef I regret I have no other suggestions.