# Random wireless disconnects, can anyone spot a problem in these logs?

Tags: wireless, networking

My laptop will randomly disconnect me from my wireless network, and sometimes on reconnecting with prompt me to re-authenticate. I have uploaded some logs to pastebin that highlight on connection and one disconnect. Maybe someone can help me out here.

http://pastebin.com/dk2s1vLy

Comment: Could you possibly say what model access point/router you are using? This is looking like an issue I had with an older router of mine.

Comment: I'm actually not certain, the only time i use the laptop would be at my school. I know they have several access points, if I see one or the router i'd update.

Comment: Okay, schools typically use Cisco access points to broadcast a repeated wifi signal across the whole campus. Does your school require sign-in to the wi-fi? If so, it could be an issue with credentials. The college I work at requires us to use some bogus Norton antivirus that doesn't run on Linux in order to be connected to wi-fi, so make sure there are no limitations like that on the network.

Comment: Nothing is needed to connect to the network, but they MAC filter some phones that can connect to the 5Ghz network. The other persons comment seems likely since there are several access points

Answer (score 1):

We see your wireless attempting to roam from among several access points, I assume all with the same name. Please check here: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: Would this be a good idea seeing as how I'm always moving around the school? or should I just set it to the AP that is close to me at that moment and change it as I go

Comment: It depends on your use case: If this happens to you when you're in the library sitting quietly: use it.  When roaming around school, remove it again.

As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the abysmally small number at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)