# Ask me before switching to a different WiFi network?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Currently in my lab, not all the WiFi APs are working properly. What happens is that my laptop switches to a not working WiFi every now and then. It's very inconvenient. Is it  possible to configure it to ask me before switching? How?

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Network Settings and find out unintended wifi networks and go for edit-->general-->uncheck the option-- automatically connect to this network when available.

I think this should solve it. You can always select the optional wifi from the main menu bar.

Comment: Thanks for the work around, but that's not exactly what I wanted.