# Error in setting wlan sensitivity

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, internet, network-manager

I use public wifi in an institute and they have got multiple routers with the same SSID spread throughout the campus. It so happens that often my laptop connects to a router with very weak signal, even though I am sitting very close to another one of the routers with the same SSID (with a very strong signal). Even after I disconnect from the weak network and connect to the strong network manually, the network stops functioning after some time and I have to do the manual reset again.

I have got Ubuntu 14.04 with the following wireless setup:

```
description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5390 [802.11 b/g/n 1T1R G-band PCI Express Single Chip]
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 84:4b:f5:70:6c:2e
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.13.0-77-generic firmware=0.34 ip=172.27.30.38 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:16 memory:c3500000-c350ffff
```

I tried to change the WLAN sensitivity using the `sudo iwconfig wlan0 sens XX` command, where I tried various values for XX like -40, 0, 20, etc. The error message displayed is

> Error for wireless request "Set Sensitivity" (8B08) :
>      SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

Comment: I suggest you try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617

Comment: @chili555 That does seem to solve the issue for me for now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @chili555, [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617) solves the issue. Essentially, if your wireless is attempting to connect to some undesirable access point, you can force it to connect to the desired AP.