# Wi-Fi Network issue in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, network-manager, atheros

I'm new to Ubuntu just install `16.04` 2 days ago. Since then I'm facing problem with Wi-Fi.
It keeps frequently changing the range while my router is just 10 feet away and which is static at a point and so is my Laptop. It keeps disconnecting frequently and at beginning it used to ask password for the network again and again even I've selected the option to remember password and connect automatically.This problem is no more and I didn't do anything specifically for this. But disconnection problem persist and have to connect it manually sometimes. Sometimes, Wi-Fi symbol at top-right corner, just goes away but I'm able to connect going in System `Settings-> Network`.
For the Network,
`modprobe -r ath9k`
`modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1`
works sometimes to bring the bars back but for sort time. (oh, there, Wi-Fi logo just disappeared from top-right)
I have searched a lot for the problem and there seems not to be a good solution other than degrading kernel which I won't prefer. I have checked for updates, dist-upgrade, full-upgrade. Everything, in my knowledge, is up to date. Could somebody please look into the issue and help me.
Oh, and Here is my `wifi-script` output: http://pastebin.com/7ZCP8JG2

**Edit:**

As suggested duplicate by [Jeremy31](https://askubuntu.com/users/300665/jeremy31) , I have tried the solution given by [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) at [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again) but that didn't solve the problem. Though it took given router as only choice to connect. When it is connected, have good signal strength but still drops out in a while.
Also shouldn't it choose best signal Access Points automatically? Why do I need to go and connect it manually through `Settings->Networks`, and if that's not possible for the new APs, why doesn't it connect to once previously connected APs automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again)  Use just `iwlist scan` instead of including wlan0.  Your wifi is switching between access points with the same name and chili555's solution should work

Comment: Thanks [Jeremy](http://askubuntu.com/users/300665/jeremy31) but that didn't help.  or did, but not exactly.

Comment: Is your problem gone?

Comment: nope. disconnection problem remains as was. have to connect manually every time. signal strength when connected is good but as explained, its not exactly a solution to manually give APs address.