# 16.04 wifi connection dropping intel 7265

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, intel

lately I've got problems with my wifi (Intel 7265). Internet connection is getting off every couple of minutes. Here is dmesg:

```
[ 3648.929744] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[ 3988.847920] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
[ 3988.848100] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
[ 3988.848116] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000041/00002000
[ 3988.848128] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
[ 3988.848136] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 6] Bad TLP               
[ 4008.741354] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 84:a4:23:61:56:31 for new auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:30
[ 4008.749319] wlp2s0: authenticate with 84:a4:23:61:56:30
[ 4008.755992] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (try 1/3)
[ 4008.758027] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 4008.761687] wlp2s0: associate with 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (try 1/3)
[ 4008.765479] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 4008.779696] wlp2s0: associated
[ 4372.142490] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 84:a4:23:61:56:30 for new auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[ 4372.148763] wlp2s0: authenticate with 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[ 4372.157644] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 1/3)
[ 4372.158556] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 4372.159956] wlp2s0: associate with 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 1/3)
[ 4372.161257] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 4372.163742] wlp2s0: associated
[ 4372.238297] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 84:a4:23:61:56:31
```

And iwconfig:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Dom88"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: 84:A4:23:61:56:31   
          Bit Rate=520 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:23   Missed beacon:0
```

Can someone please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You may be too far from the AP, or you selected a busy channel, or someone is attacking your AP. This is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: This option is not for 7265.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wireless card is dropping to roam to a different access point. You can see in *dmesg* that it leaves 84:a4:23:61:56:30 to connect to 84:a4:23:61:56:31. I suspect that these are the 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz channels of your router.

I suggest that you try binding Network Manager to one or the other like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

If this is ineffective, rename the SSIDs to something like *router2.4* and *router5*. Connect to one and stick to it.

Comment: A perfect answer. I missed that in the log. Intel chipsets like to roam.