# wifi 2.4 and 5ghz connection issues

Tags: wireless

I have LTS 16 Ubuntu on a brand new Dell laptop. Its worked ok with wifi when I've taken it out of the house. However, in my house under the list of available wifi networks my home router is there twice - once as 5ghz and once as 2.4. (I was told to configure it like this by Apple technical support before I switched to Linux).
I am able to connect to either and get internet, but it drops out after a minute or so, which is obviously *very* annoying. I am then able to reconnect, but then it just totally drops out again after another minute. The wifi symbol itself always continues to indicate that I have a good level of signal strength even when a browser tells me I am not connected to the internet.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the Apple router, not an issue with your laptop.

Comment: @ Patrick Negus Its not an apple router. Its a standard BT (British telecoms) hub.  I was having trouble connecting to wifi on my old apple mac desktop some time ago so added the second wifi option back then.

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/832324/16-04-wifi-connection-dropping-intel-7265/832364#832364

Comment: @OllieWilliams Sorry `bout that. Use chili555's link.