# My Ubuntu 16.04 keeps disconnecting from the Wi-Fi (eduroam). Why?

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, atheros

I haven't noticed any pattern and I'm sure the Wi-Fi works perfectly because I have no problems with the same computer using Windows 10. The Wi-Fi doesn't turn off though, it simply disconnects from the network and reconnects after about a couple of minutes.

I ran this and got:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2234]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Also running `dmesg`

Among the many messages the last one is:

```
[ 3818.806656] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 5 dBm as advertised by 00:23:eb:39:28:21
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your wireless card is attempting to roam to another instance of eduroam from among the several that I suspect are nearby. Confirm:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

You can also check:

```
dmesg | grep assoc
```

I think you will find that your card is trying to associate with one and then another instance of eduroam. They will each have a distinct MAC address; something like a4:2b:b0:dc:45:99 and a4:2b:b0:dc:45:88 or some such. If that is the case, you may have better luck if you bind Network Manager to the MAC address of the strongest access point: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: Seems like you were right, many Eduroam cells appeared in the scan list. I just followed the instructions on the other question. Let's see if it's better now. Thank you!

Comment: EduROAM, indeed!!

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230963) discusssion on the Arch Linux forum.

The problem seems to be the use of dhcpcd. In the discussion it is suggested to use dhclient instead. See the discussion for detailed instructions.

Comment: @MPE2016 Can you **[edit]** this to expand it with details about how to switch to dhclient?

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu 20.04 does not use dhcpcd.