# how to isolate ubuntu wifi issues - there is a specific router where my connection keeps dropping

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros

I have Ubuntu 14.04. At university I use eduroam wifi and that works fine. At home I use bt hub 6 wifi and that also works fine. However, my friend has a bt hub 4 and the wifi connection keeps "dropping". I can connect to it, it'll work for a while, it'll still be connected but it'll stop working. Sometimes if I keep connected for a while then it starts to work again. I'm not sure how to isolate what is causing the problem.

my wireless card is a qualcomm atheros (QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter)

The BT hub has 2 frequences - 2.4 and 5. both have different ssids and so I dont think it should be a connection issue. I can connect to both and the internet will work momentarily/intermittently on both. If I disconnect and reconnect, it seems to work fine for a while too. 
Just FYI here's a link to the BT smart hub (https://www.shop.bt.com/learnmore/bt-branded-products-and-services/bt-smart-hub/)

Comment: Do you have Windows on your laptop? Does the wifi work correctly there? I assume he doesn't have any disconnection problems with his devices?

Comment: Eduroam you say?? This may be useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/841620/my-ubuntu-16-04-keeps-disconnecting-from-the-wi-fi-eduroam-why/841624#841624 Also this: http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2016/03/bt-home-hub-5-tips-tricks-settings/

Comment: @Will I don't have a dual boot, so it's just ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I've tried the solution posted in the eduroam question, maybe its the wifi trying to connect to the many bt networks or the bt-with-fon thing.. if it works I would mark it as a solution =D thanks

Comment: @chili555 it that doesnt seem to be the problem.

Comment: @canatanit may not help but in days of yore I found my connection (even on Windows) was a lot more stable if I manually assigned an IP instead of relying on DHCP. If your friend is running DHCP you'd have to be careful not to take an address it might assign to someone else, but If you just go up into the 192.168.1.70-80 range it's unlikely a home network would have that many devices (obviously check his subnet, it may not be 192.168.1.x)

Comment: @Will It didn't seem to work :(

Comment: Sorry @canatan, as I said it was a long shot. I take it your friend's connection to his wifi is always steady? What kind of authentication is he using, WEP or WPA? I used to have problems with WEP too but that was many years ago. He should be (and likely is) using WPA anyway but it's worth checking. I would also be worth temporarily disabling security on the network just to eliminate authentication as a possible source. It could just be a case of starting from basics - bog standard connection with no security - then adding the different aspects of the network until it fails.