# Dual boot - Ubuntu Mate 18 / Windows 10 : issue with Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

For ultra specific reasons, I created a dual boot Ubuntu Mate 18.10 / Windows 10 and the last "bug" I need to fix is the Intel wifi driver for my card ( Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] ) on my msi GF63 8RC.

The problem is if my wifi card works everytime on the Windows, on Linux it seems not to be the case.

For example, when it works, it got this by `dmesg` :

```
[   22.634376] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   22.815281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.c0e03d94.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   24.464530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   24.515472] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 7c:2a:31:a6:80:24
[   24.972323] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   25.072145] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   45.872215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
```

but when it didn't work :

```
[   16.387791] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.464190] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110
```

The full wireless-info when everything works :
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h3JGcwstPS/

Thanks for your help :)

PS:  My  `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` if needed :

```sh
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Comment: In what situations it doesn't work? Is it perhaps when you reboot from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: After I finish what I have to do on each OS, I shutdown it.
The thing is I suspect that Windows somehow blocks the iwlwifi but since I didn't have a man page to find out what could means this -110 error code ....

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is near EOL. Consider to upgrade it to 19.04.

Comment: thanks for the reminder: honestly I sometimes prefer a better tested version that a new one directly ( with exceptions of course like python ).  As my nvidia drivers work, I got no real reasons to do that in this dual bool test (I moved yesterday from 18.04 to 18.10 as the wifi driver requires a kernel >= 4.15 from what I read on some forums )

Comment: Reviewers: [Please don't flag old questions as EOL](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16132/please-dont-flag-old-questions-as-eol)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi lar_disable=Y
```

If it seems to solve the issue, then I suggest that you make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi lar_disable=Y"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, first time I ever see this option in modprobe command ...
I will try your commands and say if it changes something .

What do you think about Wi-Fi / Bluetooth coexistence ? https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Troubleshooting and https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#wi-fibluetooth_coexistence

Comment: I dount that BT coexist is relevant to the error in your *dmesg*. You aren't, as far as I see, having bluetooth troubles.

Comment: In case of, I disabled my BT ... I included my default iwlwifi.conf iif you need that

Comment: ( I will answer you tomorrow : it seems hard to reproduce on my wifi networks (2.4Ghz, 5Ghz) except on this 'eduroam' in university )

Comment: Please see my posts about eduroam: https://askubuntu.com/questions/841620/my-ubuntu-16-04-keeps-disconnecting-from-the-wi-fi-eduroam-why/841624#841624

Comment: I made a new report when I got connected on eduroam ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h3JGcwstPS/ ) : please check :) . PS: I added your line in my conf file but I cannot see any difference yet ...

Comment: Your new paste looks perfect; I see no issues at all. When it does *not* work, is there any difference if it is a reboot or a cold boot? Can you please try each and see and then report?

Comment: I tried both in the past and it fails so I suspected hibernate mode of Windows that may lock wifi card, etc... . My current settings ( disable the BT , disable fastboot in Windows / BIOS ,  add the options lar_disable=Y and bt_coex_active=0  in conf file ) looks like to work but let's see Friday if it still holds