# Trying to change frequency channel for wireless network

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have a problem with my wireless network, in that probably there is some interference in my channel, because I'm sharing my wi-fi with many people, and there are other networks in the area that use the same frequency channel. Wi-fi analyzing tools are consistently showing that my connection is in the worst possible channel.

I live in student dormitories, so the connection settings might be unusual. For some reason, I'm unable to access router settings, although I know what router address is. So, I tried using iwconfig command in the terminal.

My network mode is set to Managed and whenever I try to change the channel there is no effect. I can switch to Ad-Hoc and change channel, and situation improves significantly after I do that, but after about 10 seconds it returns to Managed mode and the starting frequency channel.

When I switch to Monitor mode I can change frequency channel, but I lose connection completely.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list` What channel do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

"For some reason, I'm unable to access router settings" is as it should be, but the Wi-Fi router is where the Wi-Fi channel is set.

You'll have to find the person responsible for the router's settings, and make a case for a channel change (which will force Everybody to reconnect).

Comment: Well, I guess that's the best option.

Comment: Maybe not. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/841620/my-ubuntu-16-04-keeps-disconnecting-from-the-wi-fi-eduroam-why/841624#841624

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. Internet is completely down today, and I have no physical access to the router, so I will have to contact person in charge. Thanks, anyways.