# System asking for network authentication again and again

Tags: networking, internet

I am using the internet access provided by the collage, and the connection process is:

- we connect to the Wifi which is not password protected
- After connecting to it, we are presented with a network login screen like this:
  [image: Image showing the network login screen]
- After logging to this page we are able to access the internet

But I have been facing problem in my Ubuntu 21.10, that it logs out of the session again and again after a short period of time, irritating me to limits.

My Firefox shows a message that you must log into network before you can login, as shown in this image:

[image: as shown in this image]

Please help regarding this issue.

### EDIT

```
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.1987] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> bound, address='My_IP_Address'
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.2035] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.2117] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.2125] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.2144] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.2173] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.2177] policy: set 'WIFI_SSID' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 10 11:31:08 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570468.2219] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 10 11:33:16 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570596.9403] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 10 11:38:16 HostName NetworkManager[1094]: <info>  [1649570896.9725] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
```

Comment: Sometimes this can be caused by "over-enthusiastic" roaming between cells - see for example [My Ubuntu 16.04 keeps disconnecting from the Wi-Fi (eduroam). Why?](https://askubuntu.com/a/841624/178692)

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Added the Journal Entry in the edit @waltinator