# My ubuntu doesn't connect to some WiFi networks (Ubuntu 20.04). Network shows up, but doesn't respond to click and connect button

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

My Ubuntu 20.04 connects to my home WiFi just fine. But, on my school, "eduroam" wifi shows up, but doesnt respond to clicks and connect button at all. I have a dual-boot system with Windows 10. On my Windows 10, both my home Wifi and school Wifi "eduroam" works fine. I have tried restarting network services on Ubuntu. But, no clue how to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Eduroam probably needs to be manually set with certificates and all. Please consult your school IT help before any random person on the internet. Something like this (pay attention to the part about "general instructions" not working): https://servicedesk.rose-hulman.edu/knowledgebase/article/KA-01010/en-us

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/841620/my-ubuntu-16-04-keeps-disconnecting-from-the-wi-fi-eduroam-why/841624#841624