# Network Problem, when trying to connect to Eduroam Wifi

Tags: networking, network-manager, lenovo, dhcp

I can connect fine to any other networks.
And I can also connect  to this wifi, when I am at the center of it, but it's like when I get a bit too far from its original startpoint it gives up on sending a DCHP response.

This is my network logs:

I also get this sometimes:
[image: Activation of network connection failed - Popup]

I have dual boot, Windows / Linux Ubuntu 22.04, and I can connect fine on my Windows. It is only on my Linux Boot it happens.
Is this my PC's fault or the schools network?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/841620/my-ubuntu-16-04-keeps-disconnecting-from-the-wi-fi-eduroam-why/841624#841624 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.