# Wifi Connection does not work anymore over the night when Laptop was locked and has a low power

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, thinkpad, wifi-direct

here is the journal of the NetworkManager:

```
Mar 04 12:59:02 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709553542.1224] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Mar 04 12:59:02 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709553542.3450] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Mar 04 13:25:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555129.7538] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 04 13:25:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555129.7539] device (enp1s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 04 13:25:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555129.7632] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 04 13:25:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555129.7637] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 04 13:25:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555129.7639] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 04 13:25:30 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555130.1495] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 04 13:25:30 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555130.1499] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 04 13:25:30 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555130.1499] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 04 13:25:30 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555130.1499] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
Mar 04 13:25:30 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555130.2018] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 04 13:25:30 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709555130.2021] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:28 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629708.1615] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Mar 05 10:08:28 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629708.1617] device (enp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 05 10:08:28 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629708.3926] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8269] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8271] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8745] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8745] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8748] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp2s0 created
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8750] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8752] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8754] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:29 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629709.8757] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9401] policy: auto-activating connection 'eduroam' (122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46)
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9407] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'eduroam' (122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46)
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9408] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9411] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9414] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9417] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'eduroam' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9417] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9427] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9429] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9430] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'eduroam' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'ssid' value 'eduroam'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP FT-EAP FT-EAP-SHA384 WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'proto' value 'RSN'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'pairwise' value 'CCMP'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'group' value 'CCMP TKIP'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9431] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9432] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9432] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9432] Config: added 'ca_cert' value '/home/david/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9432] Config: added 'altsubject_match' value 'DNS:zar.tugraz.at;DNS:zar1.tugraz.at;DNS:zar2.tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9432] Config: added 'identity' value 'punisher20@tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9432] Config: added 'anonymous_identity' value 'anonymous@tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:08:31 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629711.9432] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.1135] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.1135] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.1175] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.1175] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.1884] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.1885] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.6462] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.6463] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.7355] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.7355] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "eduroam"
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.7355] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.7356] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:08:32 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629712.7360] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 05 10:08:36 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629716.7101] agent-manager: agent[e7d56ae0dc220a07,:1.84/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.1202] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.1202] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.1208] device (wlp2s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.1509] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.1509] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.1529] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.1530] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.2202] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Mar 05 10:09:11 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629751.2202] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.5862] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.5863] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.5866] device (wlp2s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.5867] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46" name="eduroam" pid=6220 uid=1000 result="succe>
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9236] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9549] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9560] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9562] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'eduroam' (122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46)
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9564] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9564] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9566] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9567] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9568] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9568] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9569] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'eduroam' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9569] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9578] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9579] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9580] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'eduroam' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9580] Config: added 'ssid' value 'eduroam'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP FT-EAP FT-EAP-SHA384 WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'proto' value 'RSN'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'pairwise' value 'CCMP'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'group' value 'CCMP TKIP'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9581] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9582] Config: added 'ca_cert' value '/home/david/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9582] Config: added 'altsubject_match' value 'DNS:zar.tugraz.at;DNS:zar1.tugraz.at;DNS:zar2.tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9582] Config: added 'identity' value 'punisher20@tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9582] Config: added 'anonymous_identity' value 'anonymous@tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:09:42 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629782.9582] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Mar 05 10:09:46 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629786.4077] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46" name="eduroam" args="802-11-wireless-security.gr>
Mar 05 10:09:46 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629786.9840] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 05 10:09:46 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629786.9841] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 05 10:09:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629790.7078] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:09:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629790.7078] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:09:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629790.7164] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:09:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629790.7164] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:09:51 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629791.2650] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 05 10:09:51 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629791.2650] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 05 10:09:53 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629793.5152] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Mar 05 10:09:53 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629793.5153] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "eduroam"
Mar 05 10:09:53 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629793.5153] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Mar 05 10:09:53 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629793.5154] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:09:53 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629793.5160] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 05 10:10:34 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629834.6640] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46" name="eduroam" args="ipv4.dns,ipv4.ignore-auto-d>
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.2295] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.2299] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <warn>  [1709629839.2303] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'eduroam'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.2306] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.2591] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.4965] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.4966] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7606] policy: auto-activating connection 'eduroam' (122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46)
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7611] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'eduroam' (122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46)
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7612] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7613] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7615] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7617] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'eduroam' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7617] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7624] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7626] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7627] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'eduroam' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7627] Config: added 'ssid' value 'eduroam'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP FT-EAP FT-EAP-SHA384 WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'ca_cert' value '/home/david/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'identity' value 'punisher20@tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7628] Config: added 'anonymous_identity' value 'anonymous@tugraz.at'
Mar 05 10:10:39 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629839.7629] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Mar 05 10:10:43 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629843.7880] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 05 10:10:43 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629843.7881] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 05 10:10:47 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629847.4894] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:10:47 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629847.4894] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 05 10:10:47 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629847.4964] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:10:47 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629847.4964] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 05 10:10:48 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629848.0446] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 05 10:10:48 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629848.0446] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 05 10:10:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629850.2871] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Mar 05 10:10:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629850.2872] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "eduroam"
Mar 05 10:10:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629850.2872] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Mar 05 10:10:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629850.2873] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:10:50 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629850.2877] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.2287] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.2291] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <warn>  [1709629895.2296] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'eduroam'
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.2296] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.2749] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.5716] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.5717] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.7765] policy: auto-activating connection 'eduroam' (122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46)
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.7770] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'eduroam' (122dc59c-bc05-4a9e-9baa-5df7c61b3f46)
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.7771] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 05 10:11:35 david-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-4 NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1709629895.7772] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
```

Comment: eduroam you say? Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/841620/my-ubuntu-16-04-keeps-disconnecting-from-the-wi-fi-eduroam-why/841624#841624

Comment: yes, but that has nothing to do with eduroam, my laptop is here the problem. I had the same issue as well with my own network at home, here i need to enter a manual IP/mask/gateway as well as DNS-Server. Automatically does not work here. there was also the same issue that i have looked my laptop over the night, with low power and on the next day, my computer cannot connect to the wlan as well.@chili555

Comment: There is quite a bit of additional information here. I suggest that you edit your question to include it.