# Can't Connect to 5GHZ wifi 16.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.10, atheros

I currently have a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter and am unable to connect to my 5GHZ wifi.

I never seem to have this problem when first installing Ubuntu 16.10, but after about a week of use, i can never seem to connect to the 5GHZ wifi.

I can still see it in my list of wireless connections, but sadly am unable to connect :(.

Here are some dmesg logs:

```
[ 2349.974517] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2354.678670] wlp5s0: authenticate with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b
[ 2354.711911] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 1/3)
[ 2354.713421] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 2/3)
[ 2354.714820] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 3/3)
[ 2354.716107] wlp5s0: authentication with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b timed out
[ 2359.277093] wlp5s0: authenticate with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b
[ 2359.310035] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 1/3)
[ 2359.311188] wlp5s0: authenticated
[ 2359.314510] wlp5s0: associate with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 1/3)
[ 2359.315939] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=2)
[ 2359.319432] wlp5s0: associated
[ 2359.325836] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 2359.325839] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 2359.325841] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 2359.325844] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 2359.325846] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 2359.325847] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 2359.325850] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 2359.335796] wlp5s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b
[ 2366.444236] wlp5s0: deauthenticated from dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[ 2373.852246] wlp5s0: authenticate with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b
[ 2373.885706] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 1/3)
[ 2373.887154] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 2/3)
[ 2373.888642] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 3/3)
[ 2373.889973] wlp5s0: authentication with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b timed out
[ 2379.338153] wlp5s0: authenticate with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b
[ 2379.371351] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 1/3)
[ 2379.372643] wlp5s0: authenticated
[ 2379.375037] wlp5s0: associate with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 1/3)
[ 2379.376461] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=2)
[ 2379.379678] wlp5s0: associated
[ 2379.381208] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[ 2379.381208] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 2379.381209] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 2379.381209] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 2379.381209] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[ 2379.381210] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 2379.381210] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[ 2379.406552] wlp5s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b
[ 2424.690405] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

It seems to be able to authenticate - but runs into the loop i'm showing above, where it authenticates, runs into some kind of error and deauthenticates (most of the time because of reason 3, but sometimes as shown below i seem to get the handshake timeout).

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your log, we see:

```
[ 2349.974517] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2354.678670] wlp5s0: authenticate with dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b
[ 2354.711911] wlp5s0: send auth to dc:53:7c:c6:b6:8b (try 1/3)
```

I assume that the MAC addresses x:8a and x:8b are the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz bands of your router. I also suspect that they have the same name. I suggest that you try binding Network Manager to one or the other like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

If this is ineffective, rename the SSIDs to something like router2.4 and router5. Connect to one and stick to it.

Comment: They are different, one is named WIFI and other WIFI-5G - so i doubt that should be the issue. I added the MAC addresses to the network manager but to no avail. Do you suspect this is mostly an authentication issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/default/crda` file and enter a country code. See if that solves your problem. It's currently defaulting to DE, when maybe it should be something else... like US?

```
sudo pico /etc/default/crda
```

or

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Also, make sure that you're using a WPA2-AES connection to your wireless router.