# Wifi very slow - ubuntu 16.04 - Centrino Advanced-N 6230

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have an HP ProBook 4431s.

After installing ubuntu 16.04 LTS, my WiFi is really slow so I have to use the LAN for now.

I tried the all the thread on Ubuntu where you select the realtek antenna after downloading Larry Finger's github repo.

My WiFi is still slow. I didn't see any improvements.

The output of ubuntu's wireless info is here:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/25350005/

I realized that my adapter was intel. After re-installing Ubuntu, the output is as follows:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/25353321/

FYI, I used to do dual boot between Windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 LTS and everything was fine. This is due to the upgrade to 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Your Ethernet is Realtek, your WiFi is Intel. Whatever you did, at best, has no effect but most likely made it worse. And you're connecting to an old b/g router so...

Comment: Your wireless adapter is the Intel. Please uninstall rtlwifi_new and reboot. Then give us a new paste.

Comment: I added the new log. Also, the internet started working better at the time I was typing this so the results might be better than they actually are. It stops working in 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a combination of the above two solutions:

1) Changed the name of the wifi from something generic like BELL101 to VINEET101

2)

> sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"

it got my internet speed from 0.3 Mbps tp 21 Mbps. It still doesn't go to 80-90 Mbps like it usually does but it is at least something I can work with. If you have any further ideas about how to increase this value, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"
```

and reboot.

Comment: I tried this before but this didn't really do anything for me. FYI, I've also tried 11n_disabled=1 option

Answer (score 0):

In your paste, we see several SSIDs named BELL101, including the one to which you are connected. I suspect that your wireless drops because it is attempting to roam to another instance of BELL101. If this is a router for which you have administrative access, I suggest that you rename it to, for example, BELL105 as it is a 5 gHz access point.

If you are unable to rename it, I suggest that you bind to the specific instance of BELL101 by MAC address, like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: I changed the Wifi name to VINEET101 and it still didn't do anything