# Extremely slow wifi on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday (dual boot with windows 10), and ever since i've been experiencing issues where the wifi is extremely slow. I have an intel wireless AC 9560 adapter. The speed on my windows partition is normal. I have already tried a lot of solutions. `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` seems to work but it maxes my speed at 20 MBps, while on windows I can get up to 200. I have no idea what to do, so help would be very much appreciated.

Result when running `sudo iwlist scan` of my wifi, (there are both 2 Ghz and 5 GHz entry in my terminal).

```
Cell 21 - Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
                    Channel:108
                    Frequency:5.54 GHz (Channel 108)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"H369A6B655A"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002824f11e46d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 56ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B4833363941364236353541
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 07304E4C202401172801172C01173001173401173801173C011740011764011E68011E6C011E70011E84011E88011E8C011E
                    IE: Unknown: 200100
                    IE: Unknown: 23021100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF0917FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D166C0D1600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: BF0CB259820FEAFF0000EAFF0000
                    IE: Unknown: C005016A000000
                    IE: Unknown: C30402020202
                    IE: Unknown: DDA60050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010E44E7AA738D2613B7D9690C1EA15A8E51021001B4B504E20576972656C6573732052616E676520457874656E6465721023001B4B504E20576972656C6573732052616E676520457874656E6465721024000631323334353610420004323034301054000800060050F20400011011000A4B504E5F5752455F4150100800020680103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180202001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 46057208010000
```

and

```
          Cell 13 - Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"H369A6B655A"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000011a1dae8653
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1228ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B4833363941364236353541
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 46053208010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1ABD081BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080500080000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD750050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001000000000000000000000000000000000102100035A5445102300035A54451024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F2040001101100095A5445204833363941100800020000103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180 050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

dmesg | grep iwl: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cT38pZpnBV/
sudo dkms status: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NRpkgB96kw/

Comment: Please try: 11n_disable=8. Any improvement?

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately the problem remains the same. I should also note that i get some very weird behaviour when i try to run a speedtest with 11n_disable=8, it goes to around 15 MBps and then it gets stuck and I get an error saying it can't find the server.

Comment: In fact, when I use `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11ac_disable=8` my speed goes up to 100 MBps before the speedtest gets stuck again, so it seems like the speed is fine but the connection just drops very often, which makes it unusable

Comment: Let's take a look at the settings in the router. Please run: `sudo iwlist scan` and edit your question to show your network only. Redact the MAC address with xxxxxx.

Comment: I edited the original post. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/947904/wifi-very-slow-ubuntu-16-04-centrino-advanced-n-6230/948038#948038 If this doesn't solve it, we'll dig a bit deeper.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the problem but I could try it. The thing is that when I boot from live usb WiFi works perfectly and it doesn’t give me errors when running dmesg. I’m thinking it has to do with drivers maybe, but I wouldn’t know how to fix it. Booting from the same kernel as the liveUSB doesn’t fix it

Comment: Please show us: `dmesg | grep iwl` from the full install and also from the USB live session. Please post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Sorry I tried to access the internet via live usb again and this time it didn't work for some reason... I think the problem may be with the linux-firmware. I've seen several solution where downgrading the linux-firmware helped. Could this be a possible fix?

Comment: Let's see: `dmesg | grep iwl` and we'll see what firmware loads and any errors or warnings related to firmware. Also, please let us see: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I edited my post to include the results. I also tried updating the kernel to 5.7.3 and doing a clean install but no improvement..

Comment: I'm having the same problem. iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 helps but makes it unbearably slow (20mbps). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and add the following at the end of the file
`options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0`

Then do `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`