# Ubuntu 17.10 WiFi: Internet stops working after some time

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

I'm on my college network and the internet stops working after some time even though the WiFi remains connected. To make it work again, I have to disconnect and reconnect, after which it works for a while before the problem reoccurs. This problem does not happen on Windows 10.

Details about Wireless Network for my laptop: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26429163/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have several suggestions that may help connectivity.

First, in your scan results, we see no fewer than *six* access points with the same name. In your wireless info, we see that your wireless device drops one instance and roams to another, looking for a better signal:

```
[ 8158.059001] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'ION@17th-Block' [AC1]> for new auth to <MAC 'ION@17th-Block' [AC8]>
[ 8158.064564] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'ION@17th-Block' [AC8]>
[ 8158.067518] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'ION@17th-Block' [AC8]> (try 1/3)
[ 8158.070584] wlp2s0: authenticated
```

I suggest that you bind your wireless connection to the strongest of the nearby instances in Network Manager using the method I describe here: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Next, I recommend that you turn off power saving in Network Manager; from the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Finally, set your regulatory domain explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.