# Force wifi to connect to preferred access point (BSSID)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 17.10

My home wifi network has two Google Wifi access points (APs). My desktop computer is running Ubuntu 17.10 and is literally a foot from one of the APs.

Unfortunately, instead of connecting to this close AP at 5GHz, it usually connects to the AP on the other side of the house at 2.4GHz, obviously creating a very slow and unreliable connection.

I have two questions:

1. Why would Ubuntu not automatically select the closer, stronger, faster AP?
2. Assuming this isn't something that happens automatically, how can I force Ubuntu to choose the better AP?

N.B.

- I found some related answers in the archives but they all seemed targeted to older versions of Ubuntu and Network Manager (pre-Gnome), and are no longer relevant.
- I'd prefer not to hardwire my computer because I have other equipment that needs to be hardwired and not enough ports.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to specific WiFi points with a different network manager.

Here a link to the other nm:
http://wicd.sourceforge.net/

Thanks for asking,
Ben