# Wireless connection not working anymore - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and my wireless connection doesn't work anymore whereas it worked in the past. I tried with different router but all the same happens. The message "connection failed activation of network connection failed" constantly pops out so it seems to keep trying connecting but fails.
It read a lot of relatively same issues but didn't come out with a solution. I disabled the proxy, nothing happens. I don't use a VPN. Terminal outputs I came up with didn't help me to found out what to fix. Here is some outputs that may help you to point out the problem :

```
===== sudo lshw -C network =====
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 3a
   serial: 74:70:fd:3d:d9:a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.1.55 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:130 memory:e1100000-e1101fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 21
   serial: 10:62:e5:a2:0c:84
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:131 memory:e1200000-e121ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s20f0u3c2
   serial: f6:34:83:93:42:13
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC Ethernet Device link=yes multicast=yes


===== ifconfig =====
enp0s20f0u3c2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::f434:83ff:fe93:4213  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether f6:34:83:93:42:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 118  bytes 6208 (6.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1682  bytes 299537 (299.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 10:62:e5:a2:0c:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 190  bytes 33006 (33.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 174  bytes 18215 (18.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xe1200000-e1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 124  bytes 8342 (8.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 124  bytes 8342 (8.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.43.84  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
    inet6 fe80::b322:a09f:1c2:72ab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 74:70:fd:3d:d9:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6298  bytes 1489707 (1.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 17013  bytes 2103759 (2.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Blank"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 58:48:22:64:35:49   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:55   Missed beacon:0

enp0s20f0u3c2  no wireless extensions.

===== iwconfig =====
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Blank"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 58:48:22:64:35:49   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:55   Missed beacon:0

enp0s20f0u3c2  no wireless extensions.



===== route -n =====
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0



===== ping -c 1 google.com =====
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Additional information asked by chili555 :

```
===== dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp =====
[    6.707092] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 34.0.1 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.742687] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    6.816083] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 74:70:fd:3d:d9:a2
[    6.908315] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.910713] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.186022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    8.433188] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    8.515954] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1212.494331] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1212.739471] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1212.795360] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1335.585811] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a
[ 1335.594483] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a (try 1/3)
[ 1335.603386] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 1335.610266] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a (try 1/3)
[ 1335.715959] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a (try 2/3)
[ 1335.827947] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a (try 3/3)
[ 1335.963648] wlp2s0: association with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a timed out
[ 1336.136132] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 1336.143910] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 1336.152794] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 1336.155746] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 1336.157595] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1336.159613] wlp2s0: associated
[ 1336.191894] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 1336.215449] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 1610.067601] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1611.214291] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1611.404232] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 1611.411889] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 1611.414318] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 1611.415594] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 1611.417509] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1611.419256] wlp2s0: associated
[ 1611.428620] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 1611.462507] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 1773.795761] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1776.152754] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 1776.154607] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 1776.156788] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 1776.159585] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 1776.161538] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1776.163265] wlp2s0: associated
[ 1776.221740] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 2212.257284] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2216.990395] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 2217.055192] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 2220.548245] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 2220.556051] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 2220.562718] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2220.563596] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 2220.565439] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 2220.567307] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2220.589263] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 2220.630750] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 2340.811403] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2341.477299] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 2343.753361] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 2343.761009] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 2343.764835] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2343.767904] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 2343.769826] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 2343.772549] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2343.780737] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 2343.816017] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 2376.382473] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2379.661515] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 2379.669293] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 2379.675472] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2379.679588] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 2379.681479] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 2379.683267] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2379.759563] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 5446.233493] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 5446.359163] wlp2s0: authenticate with 58:48:22:64:35:49
[ 5446.366508] wlp2s0: send auth to 58:48:22:64:35:49 (try 1/3)
[ 5446.382687] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 5446.383702] wlp2s0: associate with 58:48:22:64:35:49 (try 1/3)
[ 5446.389240] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 58:48:22:64:35:49 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 5446.394334] wlp2s0: associated
[ 8655.798445] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from 58:48:22:64:35:49 (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 8671.027105] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 8671.474290] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[ 8671.483123] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 8671.485389] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 8671.487707] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[ 8671.489557] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 8671.491333] wlp2s0: associated
[ 8671.510804] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 8671.529698] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[16328.425982] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[19875.406133] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[19875.475403] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[19878.960565] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[19878.969077] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[19878.975249] wlp2s0: authenticated
[19878.979956] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[19878.982137] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[19878.985430] wlp2s0: associated
[19879.000637] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[19879.051291] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[22316.866816] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[22321.244325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[22321.489274] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[22321.578514] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[22325.081814] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[22325.089608] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[22325.095648] wlp2s0: authenticated
[22325.099195] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (try 1/3)
[22325.101075] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[22325.103524] wlp2s0: associated
[22325.104472] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
[22325.118334] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[22453.191928] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b for new auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a
[22453.202593] wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a
[22453.209501] wlp2s0: send auth to 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a (try 1/3)
[22453.219291] wlp2s0: authenticated
[22453.231579] wlp2s0: associate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a (try 1/3)
[22453.236579] wlp2s0: RX ReassocResp from 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a (capab=0x31 status=0 aid=2)
[22453.254559] wlp2s0: associated

===== nmcli dev wifi list =====
IN-USE  SSID                         MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
    Livebox-2E10                 Infra  112   540 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
    Orange_Swiatlowod_E0F0_5GHz  Infra  52    540 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
    SCG200_LBO                   Infra  100   270 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
    SCG200_Tunnel                Infra  100   270 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
*       Audio3D                      Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  66      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
    Livebox-5DC6                 Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
    Livebox-85e4                 Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
    Livebox-A9A4                 Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
    Orange_Swiatlowod_E0F0       Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
    Livebox-828C                 Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
    Livebox-848c                 Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1
```

I'll post other outputs if needed.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Your wireless appears to be connected and you have an IP address. I don’t understand the problem. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From what I have observed since this morning, from time to time the connection appears again (like for 5 minutes) and then the same problem occurs for a quite long time. Really don't know what is going on

Comment: Let's look for clues in the log. Please run: `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp` and also: `nmcli dev wifi list` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I added this information to the original post. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

We quite clearly see your wireless roaming from among three access points looking for a better connection. This accounts for the annoying drops and reconnects.

> wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9a
>
> wlp2s0: authenticate with 2c:39:96:2c:56:9b
>
> wlp2s0: authenticate with 58:48:22:64:35:49

I suspect that the first two are the 2.4 GHz segment and the 5 GHz segment of the same router that is set to auto select the frequency and the channel. If this is a router over which you have administrative privileges, I recommend that you rename the segments; something like peehay2.4 and peehay5. Used a fixed channel for each and use WPA2-AES, sometimes called CCMP. I do not recommend any mixed mode and especially not TKIP.

You may also have better luck binding your wireless to the best access point by its MAC address like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)