# Wifi issues in HP laptop + Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, hp

I've booted my HP Pavilion laptop with Ubuntu 16.04, though I installed wifi drivers (Mediatek), I'm still facing problems! Sometimes the connection gets disconnected by itself and I've to reconnect again.
I've run wireless-info script and pasted the output in https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wSQzBhVRhk/

Someone please help!

Comment: 65 access points detected on 3 channels, half of them *on a single channel*: Seems like a rather congested environment. I'm not surprised connections drop - that's a lot of same-channel interference.

Comment: You might have better luck if you bind your wireless to one specific MAC address like this possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @user1752720 If you have any influence over the folks who run the WiFi, suggesting they acquire an 802.11ac (preferred, introduced in 2013) or 802.11n router (introduced in 2007). There are 13 non-interfering 5GHz channels available through 802.11ac and 802.11n, whereas there are only three non-interfering channels for 802.11b and 802.11g in the 2.4GHz band. 802.11ac and 802.11n also allow multiple channels to be 'bonded' together for increased throughput.