# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Intel Wireless/WiFi dropping in and out

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, 20.04, iwlwifi

**Summary of the problem:**

Since upgrading from `Ubuntu 19.04` to `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` I notice in VOIP calls I was cutting in and out. I then noticed that this was happening regularly and the wifi was reauthenticating with the WAP.

**Details and any research already conducted:**

I ran the `dmesg` command to see if any diagnostic information was being logged for the problem and I could see the below:

```
$ dmesg -T | grep "wlp0s20f3\|iwlwifi"
[Sat May 16 23:00:43 2020] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 90:02:18:6f:0e:be for new auth to 80:72:15:1c:c1:72
[Sat May 16 23:00:43 2020] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 80:72:15:1c:c1:72
[Sat May 16 23:00:43 2020] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 80:72:15:1c:c1:72 (try 1/3)
[Sat May 16 23:00:43 2020] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[Sat May 16 23:00:43 2020] wlp0s20f3: associate with 80:72:15:1c:c1:72 (try 1/3)
[Sat May 16 23:00:43 2020] wlp0s20f3: RX ReassocResp from 80:72:15:1c:c1:72 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[Sat May 16 23:00:43 2020] wlp0s20f3: associated
[Sat May 16 23:02:10 2020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[Sat May 16 23:02:11 2020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[Sat May 16 23:02:12 2020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[Sat May 16 23:02:13 2020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[Sat May 16 23:36:54 2020] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 80:72:15:1c:c1:72 for new auth to 90:02:18:6f:0e:be
[Sat May 16 23:36:54 2020] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 90:02:18:6f:0e:be
[Sat May 16 23:36:54 2020] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 90:02:18:6f:0e:be (try 1/3)
[Sat May 16 23:36:54 2020] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[Sat May 16 23:36:54 2020] wlp0s20f3: associate with 90:02:18:6f:0e:be (try 1/3)
[Sat May 16 23:36:54 2020] wlp0s20f3: RX ReassocResp from 90:02:18:6f:0e:be (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
```

I am using an Intel Wireless controller.

```
$ lspci | grep Wireless
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 11)
```

Further information can be found at pastebin:

Wireless Diagnostic Script Output: [Click Here](https://pastebin.com/UTpZhHJA)

**What I have already tried:**

I have already tried the below:

1. Try the proprietary driver vs the opensource driver (Made no difference).
2. Forced the wireless card to only use the 2.4 band.
3. Adjusted the power save settings for the wifi card to disable.

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

4. Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and installed all updates available.

I have already had a look at existing posts and they don't seem to be having the same problem as me so any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried to provide as much information as I can but please let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: I had the same issue when I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and I changed internet providers (I did not have any issues with my old one which had a separate modem and router). With my new provider (that has an integrated modem/router), the issue was partially solved by disabling the Wi-Fi power management, unfortunately my internet speed is very unstable (fluctuates from 3Mbps to 35Mbps). I am getting 48Mbps in a Win OS.

Answer (score 2):

> I was cutting in and out. I then noticed that this was happening
>   regularly and the wifi was reauthenticating with the WAP.

I would expect no less! In reviewing your wireless diagnostic results, we see that you are connected to the access point SKYEBYCK. Your scan results show no less than *eight* instances of SKYEBYCK. We also see in the message log, evidence that your wireless is disconnecting from one instance to reconnect to another, looking for a better signal.

```
[15898.927207] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP <MAC 'SKYEBYCK' [AC8]> for new auth to <MAC 'SKYEBYCK' [AC11]>
[15898.940638] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with <MAC 'SKYEBYCK' [AC11]>
[15898.950051] wlp0s20f3: send auth to <MAC 'SKYEBYCK' [AC11]> (try 1/3)
[15898.994714] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
<snip>
[16996.211084] wlp0s20f3: associate with <MAC 'SKYEBYCK' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[16996.223252] wlp0s20f3: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'SKYEBYCK' [AC1]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
[16996.242642] wlp0s20f3: associated
```

In the diagnostic report, AC8, AC11 and AC1 are redactions of the MAC addresses for the access points.

I recommend that you bind Network Manager to the MAC address of the SKYEBYCK instance with the strongest signal strength. You can find it with:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

Here is a post that describes the process:  [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: Thanks @chili555 but something must have changed between 19.04  and 20.04 because the behaviour is different. I am pretty far away from the WAP which probably doesn't help matters.

Anyway, let me test and get back to you and mark this as fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. It tooks me weeks to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not affiliated with the  tlp software. I had a similar issue with my Inspiron 5759 laptop that has an Intel Wireless 3160 adapter that also uses the iwlwifi driver. I saw somewhere someone was saying it's a power issue, but they didn't elaborate a fix or anything. I installed TLP and am just using the default power profile and I haven't experienced issues since.
https://linrunner.de/tlp/

Comment: This looks like it *could* be spam, as it is really only promoting a product... Are you affiliated to the company in any way? If not, and this is a genuine solution, then please edit and expand why you think this solution works for you.

Comment: tlp is open source software, easily installed from apt repositories, for what it's worth.  I use it for a bunch of power control stuff myself, it enables you to modify behaviour on or off battery, extend how long the battery lasts etc.