# How to disable 802.11ac on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

I want to know how to disable the 802.11ac in Ubuntu 21.04 on my laptop.
I'm new to Ubuntu,my laptop has an Intel AX201 wireless card,which supports 802.11ac.But I don't want to use the 5GHz signal because my room is far from router and the signal is weak.I tried to google this question,but got no answer.
The infomation of my card:

```
# lshw -class network
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 40:ec:99:f3:ed:91
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.3.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:c551c000-c551ffff
```

Comment: The answer might be in `modinfo -p iwlwifi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't want to use the 5GHz signal because my room is far from
> router and the signal is weak.

However, disabling 802.11ac won’t prevent your wireless adapter from connecting to the 5 gHz segment of the router as 802.11n will still be available on 5 gHz.

If you wish to connect only to the longer range 2.4 gHz segment, there are two options. First, if this is a router over which you have administrative privileges,  I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Then, in Network Manager connect only to myrouter2.4.

Second, you can ask Network Manager to bind to the MAC address of the 5 gHz segment only, like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: Thank you.I used the first method,and it solve my problem

Comment: Awesome, glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers with a similar problem will appreciate it.