# wifi keeps switching to different network

Tags: networking, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Latitude 5500 laptop. I have 2 wifi networks, and every 30 minutes or so it will switch from one network to the other. I don't have this issue with any other device (multiple phones, laptops, and desktop computers). Is there a way I can tell it to just connect to a specific wifi network and not switch without asking?

What could cause it to switch networks like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your settings, then wifi, select the network you dont want to connect to automatically and uncheck the radio button connect automatically.

The system will switch to the better range networks automatically if you
have the connect automatically setting turned on[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG8PI.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless is dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

If renaming is not feasible, then bind Network Manager to the 5 gHz segment like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

The MAC address of the 5 gHz segment will be different form the 2.4 gHz segment.